# What does it mean by UnboundLocalError? (python)

Tags: python, variables

I want to write a program that uses a while loop to total up the even integers from 1 to 20.
This is my code in Python IDLE.

```python
#Important Notes
#===============
#You MUST use the following variables
#   - total
#   - number

#START CODING FROM HERE
#======================

#Set number value
number = 2
total = 0
#Check closest object
def total_num(number):
    while number % 2 == 0 and number <=20:
        total = total + number
        number = number + 2

    print('The total is {}'.format(total)) #Modify to display the total
    return total #Do not remove this line

#Do not remove the next line
total_num(number)

#output 110
```

The errors I get are:

```python
total_num(number)
and
total = total + number
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 0):

`total` is declared outside of function therefore it is a `global` variable, to call it you need to declare it as `global` first

```
number = 2
total = 0
#Check closest object
def total_num(number):
    global total #<<----- here
    while number % 2 == 0 and number <=20:
        total = total + number
        number = number + 2

    print('The total is {}'.format(total)) #Modify to display the total
    return total #Do not remove this line

#Do not remove the next line
total_num(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

just initialize total value `(total = 0)` inside the function.
when you initialize total variable inside the function `foo` it will work fine and you wont need to use `global`.

```
#Set number value
number = 2
#Check closest object
def total_num(number):
    total = 0 #declare total variable here instead.
    while number % 2 == 0 and number <=20:
        total = total + number
        number = number + 2

    print('The total is {}'.format(total)) #Modify to display the total
    return total #Do not remove this line

#Do not remove the next line
total_num(number)
```